# How to expose an 'EventTarget' object from preload.js

Tags: javascript, events, electron

Is it possible to expose a Javascript `EventTarget` object from **preload.js** via `exposeInMainWorld()` to the web application which runs in context isolation mode? When I try this, the object exposed to **renderer.js**, is just a simple object which is not of type `EventTarget` anymore.

As a workaround I'm now dispatching my events directly to `document` in **preload.js** and then I'm adding corresponding listeners on application side, but this pollutes the `document` namespace unnecessarily.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a little bit of your code here. I'm _feeling_ your context bridge is dropping properties as [defined here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge/#parameter--error--return-type-support). I would regardless suggest you take a read of my post about Electron as it may provide information helpful to you: https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/

Comment: Thanks @reZach! Yes I assume that it is not possible due to the limitations mentioned on the page that you've linked in your post. I knew that page already, I was just wondering whether there is a recommended way how to handle such a scenario correctly. I think my workaround (doing everything in the global document context) is not the best way.